# Create woven image list

Tags: css, math, vuejs2, material-design, modulo

I'm looking to realise a woven image list such as specified in the material design guidelines :

[Link to guideline](https://material.io/design/components/image-lists.html#weaved-image-list)

[Implementation by shrine i'm aiming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cSr6.png)

The principle is to create differents ratios for images in an image list. I'm looking to do this using javascript. I though i could deal with modulo (%) however I'm bad in mathematics so i can't do much better than even and odd which is not enough because one line upon two should invert container sizes.

To resolve this problem i have the index of the current image. The list's size may vary. Each row contains 4 images, I alternate width between 30 et 20. A pseudo-code to illustrate the current state of my code which is not working

```
for (index : images) {
    if (index % 2 == 0)
        width = 20%
    else if (index % 2 != 0)
        width = 30%;
}
```

**EDIT**

here is the real code behind and how it renders. It's Vue.js code :

```
<v-flex v-for="(pic, index) in accomodation.images" v-bind:class="{flex30 : index % 2 == 0, flex20 : index % 2 != 0}">
    <img height="auto" style="width:100%" :src="pic.data"></img>
</v-flex>
```

The interesting part is in v-bind:class, index is the current index of the image

Here is how it renders :

[My render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcaRF.png)

Here is how i want it to be rendered (classes were manually changed here) :

[Expected render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4sdl.png)

I'm looking for the algorithme (the langage doesn't matter much but js is still preferred) which could perform this.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT 2**

css classes are the following :

```
.flex20 {
    max-width:20%;
    flex-basis:20%;
}
.flex30 {
    max-width:30%;
    flex-basis:30%;
}
```

The aim of such classes is to change the size, however, The point is more on how to get those classes applied to reproduce the desired pattern :

A B A B
B A B A

Comment: Please share your _real_ code, a [mcve], not pseudo-code.

Comment: I saw you have expected css class for your div. Can you show your css class at the moment?